# ServiceNow - What are the security roles user needs to have to add/delete sys_users via the Rest api?

Tags: servicenow

I am working with the ServiceNow Rest Api. When a user provides username and password to connect to the rest api I need to validate whether the user can add/remove (Manage users) users in sys_user table. How can I do that check?

I was referring to following Get table Rest api request, to check user whether he has nessasary roles,

https://.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_has_role?sysparm_fields=role%2Crole.name%2Cuser%2Cuser.name%2Cuser.sys_id%2Cuser.department&
sysparm_query=role%3D3d43716d0f6002003a2d47bce1050e0d%5EORrole%3Dac73b52d0f6002003a2d47bce1050eec&sysparm_display_value=true

What roles do I need to check? or is there an easier/better way to perform this (look for table permissions)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The sys_user table itself is protected by ACLs that ensure whoever is accessing it, whether from the primary user interface or via web services, is authorized to make changes. So from that perspective, there is nothing you special you need to do from the REST API to verify the user has permission. You just need to ensure the ACLs are defined in the sys_user table the way it makes sense for your use case. Out of box the ACLs I believe allow only users with 'admin' role to make changes to the sys_user table.

Comment: Asked a related question here: https://community.servicenow.com/message/1083838#1083838... i.e. as REST documentation implies that there's no per-user permissions for those accounts with the rest role.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an OOB configuration, your API User would need the `user_admin` role in addition to any soap / web services roles.

See these OOB ACLs on `sys_user`:

Create:
https://YOURINSTANCE.service-now.com/sys_security_acl.do?sys_id=f802c1d44f230200712553418110c752

Delete:
https://YOURINSTANCE.service-now.com/sys_security_acl.do?sys_id=93c234f1072200000ca55720e1021e5f